# Type error with Redux Toolkit and Next Redux Wrapper in typescript?

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I am trying to get one solutions. I ask several question with the same matter in stacks. But No one answering my questions. If someone answer this, the give wrong information. Can anybody help me, please. I need really your help, please. Please give some time from your valuable time.

I want to configure Redux toolkit (`@reduxjs/toolkit`) with next redux wrapper(`next-redux-wrapper`). But I am facing one problem.

The error is-

`Type error: Type '(state: ReturnType<typeof combinedReducer>, action: AnyAction) => any' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<CombinedState<{ counter: { value: any; }; }>, AnyAction> | ReducersMapObject<CombinedState<{ counter: { value: any; }; }>, AnyAction>'.`

Error occurred in Store.ts-

```
import { Action, AnyAction, combineReducers, configureStore, ThunkAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createWrapper, HYDRATE } from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import { getMovies } from "./Reducer/movieReducer";

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
    counter: getMovies
});

const reducer = (state: ReturnType<typeof combinedReducer>, action: AnyAction) => {
    if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
        const nextState = {
            ...state,
            ...action.payload,
        };
        return nextState;
    } else {
        return combinedReducer(state, action);
    }
};

export const makeStore = () => configureStore({ reducer }); //I am facing problem here in reducer

type Store = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>;

export type AppDispatch = Store['dispatch'];
export type RootState = ReturnType<Store['getState']>;
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
    ReturnType,
    RootState,
    unknown,
    Action<string>
>;

export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore);
```

I find error in this line-

`export const makeStore = () => configureStore({ reducer });`

You can see image for better understanding error-
[image]

Please give some time from your valuable times. Please help me. I am stacking it over 1 month. I am trying but not getting any solutions. Please help me. Please help me.

Comment: Hard to see from the description alone. If you could provide a code sandbox or a github repo I can help you :)

Comment: Here is Github repo- https://github.com/siamahnaf198/movies-list

Comment: @LaurenzHonauer. Please. Help me. I am stacking with this for 1 month. I am not getting any solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every reducer has to be able to be called with `undefined`.

To fix the proble, do

```
const reducer = (state: ReturnType<typeof combinedReducer>, action: AnyAction) => {
```

Although I'd do

```
const reducer: typeof combinedReducer = (state, action) => {
```

instead.

Comment: You are boss. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Is there actually an Error happening in the App?

To me, it looks like Typescript just doesn't understand that your `reducer` actually is of Type `Reducer`.

When I add the following, the error disappears:
[image: Screenshot of change]

Comment: Please don't do a `Reducer` annotation that omits the `State` generic, that will erase all state type info over the whole app.